# What type of concerns should I have when considering the full page cache in module development?

Tags: full-page-cache, magento-enterprise, module

I'm creating a module with blocks that will be displayed on the category page in Enterprise 1.12.

I'm trying to wrap my head around the full page cache and what needs to be done to implement my module to make use of it.   Is it enough to just have the block extend core/template and have that output go into the full page cache in magento or is my thinking wrong on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess what I am looking for is resources to explain FPC in more detail and how to make use of it.  This seems to be a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120413/how-do-i-include-a-dynamic-block-in-the-product-page-with-full-page-caching-turn/9125519#9125519

Answer (score 2):

This gives a good understanding.

http://www.kingletas.com/2012/09/how-does-magento-full-page-cache-works.html

Comment: It's important to provide summaries of linked content because links can break.